# Where not in with a belongs to relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two table named 'districts' & 'division' as follows:

`division` table

[image]

`districts` table

[image]

division model hasMany `districts`

Now I want to get all division with districts except some districts. I am trying as follows:

```
$divisionWithDistricts = Division::with('districts')->whereNotIn('districts.id',$districtsAlreadyUsed)->get();
```

Here districtsAlreadyUsed is an array of district ids. I got `Unknown column 'districts.id'` error. It was so easy if district_id was present at `division` table. How can I get such data at this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```php
$divisionWithDistricts = Division::with(['districts' => function($query) use($districtsAlreadyUsed) {
    $query->whereNotIn('id', $districtsAlreadyUsed);
}])
->get();
```